# How to prevent file owner from changing/deleting their own file? Linux CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, access-control-list

This is NOT your standard "how do permissions work" question!

I'm thinking the answer will probably involve ACL, but I don't know how exactly.

I've messed around with standard permissions, guid, sticky bit, etc. Doesn't work.

What I want:
User will upload files. User will have ability to change permissions on files to allow execution. But user will not be able to change the contents of file once it's created. And user will not be able to delete the file.

Please help! I've been tearing my hair out for hours!

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers but so far they don't seem to address how to have this work automatically for newly-created files.

Possible solution:

```
find -mtime -1 -exec chattr +i '{}' \+
```

2nd possible solution:

```
inotifywait -m -e create --format %f .
```

Now I just need to figure out to pipe that to chattr.

Comment: *but so far they don't seem to address how to have this work automatically for newly-created files* -- Can't happen. Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: @tylerl "but so far they don't seem to address how to have this work automatically for newly-created files -- Can't happen. Sorry to disappoint" -Anything is possible. See my suggestion, which I'm about to add to my edit.

Comment: The way that it's possible is to have whatever mechanism you used to upload the files ALSO run chattr. That's different from automatic

Comment: "The way that it's possible is to have whatever mechanism you used to upload the files ALSO run chattr. That's different from automatic" Hmmm, no I don't think FTP program could run chattr. cron is close to automatic, but not ideal. Ideally, some program would be notified at file creation and immediately run chattr. Something like that...

Comment: I'm going to have to ask you again: **What are you trying to do?**

Comment: I want users to be able to create files, but not delete them. This is because users are going to upload scripts and execute them and I need to be able to examine those scripts to see what they do. I can't do that if they create, execute, and delete them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton oh and by the way, I did add a comment to that other question, attempting to clarify what I'm trying to do. Hopefully this one is more clear. The other question: http://serverfault.com/questions/448868/how-to-set-ftp-upload-umask-so-uploads-cannot-be-deleted

Comment: By what transfer mechanisms will users move these files?  Will they also have interactive access?

Comment: @MadHatter What do you mean interactive access? They will upload by FTP and can make changes by SSH as well.

Comment: By "interactive access" I mean what it normally means: access to a shell running on the machine ("make changes by ssh" is highly ambiguous, and doesn't answer the question; do you mean "interactive login via ssh", or "using sshfs", or "using SFTP, which is part of the SSH subsystem", or something else again?).  If you're willing to restrict their access to ftp, this is all easy to do.  If you want to add interactive access all bets are off, and I'd be suprised if you ever find a solution short of hacking the kernel.

Comment: @MadHatter The user will be executing the script through their remote terminal by SSH, secure shell. The user also has FTP access. I assume they will upload by FTP, execute across SSH, then delete either way. But they must have SSH access to execute the script. I don't see why I would have to hack the kernel. All I have to do is change ownership of the files they upload so that they can execute but not write.

Comment: No.  You also have to change things so they can't delete (under UNIX, file deletion permission is handled completely separately from file write permission), and you want it to happen automatically.  As tylerl said at the very beginning, that's the trickiest bit.  Saying that you're sure it's simple ("all I have to do is...") doesn't make it simple; it's not.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use 'chattr'

Example:

```
urug@nada.cclan:~$ sudo chattr +i plik.txt 
urug@nada.cclan:~$ rm plik.txt 
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file `plik.txt'? y
rm: cannot remove `plik.txt': Operation not permitted
urug@nada.cclan:~$ chattr -i plik.txt 
chattr: Operation not permitted while setting flags on plik.txt
```

Comment: Very nice but how to have it automatically set at the time of file creation? See edit to my post.

Comment: You can use 'inotify' or similar mechanism to do it automatically http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/inotify.7.html

Comment: Another helpful app: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/inoticoming.1.html

Comment: those look good but will it work on CentOS. Your link is for Ubuntu.

Comment: inotify is universal, not related to any distro. You need only to implement mechanism that will use it. I googled a little for you, http://nixcraft.com/centos-rhel-fedora/13622-monitor-ftp-server-send-email-whenever-new-files-uploaded-created.html

Comment: I installed inotify. I got it to output filenames to stdout. I know this is a dumb question, but now how do I get `chattr`, or heck even `chown` to execute whenever `inotify` outputs a new file?

Answer (score 3):

Use attributes

```
sudo chattr +i /path/to/file
```

Remove "immutable" flag with

```
sudo chattr -i /path/to/file
```

That'll prevent you from changing permission on the file, though. So you'll need some way to (as root) add execute permission or whatever upon user request. Also, attributes are not added by default; you have to put in somethin that will do that to.

I'll leave that bit as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

SELinux might be one way to solve it - associate unique type with all users that will have this "reduced ability". Set SELinux policy to allow file creation in this directory for those user types but not modification etc. In theory - should work. See [Gentoo SELinux Tutorial](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SELinux/Tutorials/How_SELinux_controls_file_and_directory_accesses), in particular pice about:

```
allow auditd_t <type>:file { <permission> };
```

then [check out  more on permissions available](http://seedit.sourceforge.net/doc/access_vectors/access_vectors.html#SECTION00041000000000000000)

Answer (score 1):

Use inotify or other watching mechanism of your choice to find and locate new files in the upload directory and move them into a new directory, for which the initial user has no permissions.